# React throwing Problem for findDOMNode Deprecated and to switch to forwardRef()

Tags: reactjs, popover, react-dom, react-ref, react-forwardref

I'm new to React and [handling React's warnings and errors](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html). So, I'm looking to understand what I'm supposed to do with [creating refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) instead of allowing [findDOMNode](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html) to happen.

I'm creating a [Popover](https://material-ui.com/components/popover/) in the [App Bar](https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/). But the Popover reference throws an error and when working on it drops out of view because my ReactDOM isn't handling it consistently. The problem is: I can't get the `ref={ref}` to handle well.

To find out more information I run React In [StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html). 
React wants a [forwardRef()](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) so it knows where the Popover is relative to the view, and therefore won't fall outside of the view. But I don't know how to. 
What to do to make the createRef and forwardRef work?

[image: Edit Material demo]

Comment: I just tried your demo and the popup appears when I click the button. So did you fix the error?

Comment: This isn't about showing up - it's about the selection aligning correctly on initial load.